# html, css, hiding bordes of a table column but keeping the content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a table which is currently looks like this:

[image]

I would like to hide the blocks where the buttons are placed but I couldn't find  solution for it.
My html code looks like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Worknumber</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
        {{#falseRow}}
        <tr> 
            <td>{{this.workNumber}}</td>
            <td>{{this.shortNote}}</td>
            <td>{{this.timeStamp}}</td>
            <td>
                <div class="makeItDone">
                    <form action="/list/{{this.id}}" method="get"> 
                        <button type="submit" class="material-icons">done</button> 
                    </form>
                </div> 
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="upDateRecord">
                    <form action="/edit/{{this.id}}" method="get">
                        <button type="submit" class="material-icons">view_list</button> 
                    </form>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {{/falseRow}} 
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

css:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    background: url(.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
table {
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;

}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
th {
    background: #c3c5c9;
}
tr {
    background: #c3c5c9;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #eee;
}
td {
    color:#000;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
}
button {
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: black;
    padding: 8px 12px 8px 12px;
    border-style: outset;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: grey;
    color: white;
}
button:hover{
    background: black;
    color: red;
}
button:active {
    background: black;
    padding: 8px 13px 8px 13px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: grey;
    color: red;
}
```

I did try { display:none; } at the button's td but it dismiss the entire block. I'm just wondering if there is any way to make the border and the background of this block invisible somehow but keeping the button in the current form and place. Maybe this design is wrong and this isn't the way to line up the buttons with the row, I'm not sure :(

Comment: Did you try `background:transparent`?

Comment: Plese insert a code to woriking on . jsfiddle?

Comment: You have set background color for `TR` and you can not override it by transparent `TD` background.

Comment: You said you want to hide the blocks, which sounds like the cell, but you want to just remove the background and border? Apply the colors to the td elements, not the row. So add a rule to remove the border and background-color of the cell.

Comment: @Cristian please do not suggest using external sites for sharing code. SO has a very easy to use internal code snippet that should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the cell colors on the td along with the border and add a class to remove it.

```css
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
}

td {
  background-color: green;
}

td.clean {
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

div {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td class="clean">4</td>
        <td class="clean">5</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I actually studying css just now and I did copy the table from some website, but you gave me good example that help me to understand the table a bit more, thanks!